# Connect-PnPOnline : Could not load type 'System.Security.SecureString'

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint-online, azure-container-instances, powershell-core

On *Azure*, I have created a windows container using *microsoft/iis:nanoserver* image. I am trying to run *SharepointPnPPowershellOnline* Cmdlets in side it and it is throwing the following exception on *Connect-PnPOnline*.

```
PS C:\> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xyz.sharepoint.com -CurrentCredentials
Could not load type 'System.Security.SecureString' from assembly 'mscorlib,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7bc...'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xyz.sharepoint.com -CurrentC ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], TypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException
```

I have installed *AzureAD*, *SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline* plugins inside windows docker container. I tried with other connection options include *AccessToken, ClientId, Get-Credentials* et., On all of these, I am facing the same issue.

[image]
[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Nano Server does not contain .NET Framework and System.Security.SecureString is also missing. You would have to [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/ways-to-install-a-package) NuGet package [System.Security.SecureString](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.SecureString/) to use it on the Nano Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas for the answer.